# Returning 1st Largest and 2nd Largest numbers

Tags: r

```
df <-   A B C D E F G H     
        0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7        
        1 2 3 8 5 6 7 4
```

Need to find the 1st and 2nd largest number in the above given data frame . Result should be as below .

```
A B C D E F G H      1st Largest      2nd Largest
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7          7                 6
1 2 3 8 5 6 7 4          8                 7
```

Comment: What did you try? Why did it not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can loop through the rows using `apply` (with `MARGIN=1`), `sort` the elements with `decreasing=TRUE` option, and get the first two elements with `head` or just `[1:2]`, transpose the output and assign it to create two new columns in 'df'.

```
 df[c("firstLargest", "SecondLargest")] <- t(apply(df, 1,
           function(x) head(sort(x, decreasing=TRUE),2)))
 df
 #  A B C D E F G H firstLargest SecondLargest
 #1 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7            7             6
 #2 1 2 3 8 5 6 7 4            8             7
```